# custom marker not showing on google api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

the XML output is here
the site is here

and here is my code

i want to put custom marker with custom image on marker the xml is showing correctly i think but the marker is not showing on the map... kindly correct or just correction thanks a lot

```
var customIcon = {
    1 : {
        icon : './img/ps.png'
    },
    }


var myLatlng, map, marker, html;

function initialize() {
  myLatlng =new google.maps.LatLng(15.976345,120.56681);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }


map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
loadStations();


}


function loadStations() { // Function to load Stations


    downloadUrl("pau_genxml.php", function(data) {
      var xml = data.responseXML;
      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");     
        var head = markers[i].getAttribute("chead");
        var hotline = markers[i].getAttribute("hotline");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/><b>Head: </b>" + head
        + "</br><b>Hotline/Contact No: </b>" + hotline;;
        var id = 1; //Initialize to match ICON id   
        var icon = customIcon[id] || {};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: point,
          icon: icon.icon           
        });
        //bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
      }
    });


}



function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: What happens if you uncomment `map: map` in `loadStations()`?

Comment: nothing happens just the same if i uncomment it ;(

Comment: Move `var map = new google.maps...` outside of the `load` function and try it again.

Comment: And the `mapOptions` and `myLatLng` too.

Comment: by doing that like putting 
    var map = new google.maps... before load function or outside it the map will not load

Comment: See my supplied answer.

Comment: the map loads but not the marker

Answer (score 0):

You've got `map` stored as a local variable in `load()` and therefore nothing in `loadStations()` can see it. Move it, and the other variables it relies on - `myLatLng` and `mapOptions` - outside of the function:

```
var customIcon = {
  1 : { icon : './img/ps.png' },
};

var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(16.006216,120.351105);

var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 9,
  center: myLatLng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);

function load() {
  // rest of your function
}
```

Comment: You moved the code incorrectly. Your code now reads `function var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(16.006216,120.351105);` and `load()`. Move the word `function` back in front of the word `load()`.

Comment: this one is giving me headache nothing happens until now

Comment: You've got another error. `ReferenceError: load is not defined`. What happened to your load function? I'm not sure I can help any more on this, sorry.

Comment: what happen to the other answer ?

Comment: Deleted in frustration I expect.

Comment: thats awesome,, hope someone be more enlighten me on this

Comment: But you keep introducing more and more errors. For instance it doesn't work at the moment because you have an `onload event` on your `<body>` element, but no load function because you removed it.

Comment: ur helping :) andy post the code soon ,,, my problem now is the info window :) soo nice   

EDIT the markers are now showing but when i bind it to show infowindow one marker will only show

Comment: Uncomment the line in `loadStations()` that calls `bindInfoWindow`. See what happens then.

Comment: thats my problem when i uncomment it only one marker will show the first one in the XML

Comment: My only suggestion is for you to take the code that's in `bindInfoWindow` and replace that commented line with it. So, don't call the function, place that function's code where that commented line is.

Comment: can i buy u coffee? thanks man,,, the solution is to create global infowindow object. var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

Comment: Yup, just figured that out myself by getting your code to work on my machine :) Got there in the end. Glad to help. Make you sure you check your console for errors in the future. Adios. Oh, and that tick by my answer, give it a click :)